# Video not playing through video.js

Tags: jquery, wordpress, video

Hi I have a video intro set up on my home page.

www.blazepictures.co.uk

The default sample video as you will be able to see is playing fine but when I use my own video URL's the play doesn't load...

I am using the WordPress plugin version and using short codes. I am simply removing the sample URL's and replacing with mine.

Also when I paste my video URL's in the address bar the browser plays them fine. So I'm not sure whats going on here.

My video files: http://www.blazepictures.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/video-intro/

Here is the default short code I am using as well that works:

```
[video mp4="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" ogg="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogg" webm="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" preload="auto" autoplay="true" width="640" height="264" id="movie-id" class="alignleft"]
```

Answer (score 4):

When referencing src in  tag using VIDEOJS, you must use a full URL, not a / or relative URL for local video content.

Instead of:

```
<source src="/file.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
```

Use:

```
<source src="http://www.blazepictures.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/video-intro/file.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
```

Video.js pulls in a .swf file from a remote CDN server. The .swf then fetches /file.mp4 relative from its domain (the CDN), which results in a failure.